# SDL Content Porter 2009 SP2 - between 2011 SP1 HR1 and 2011 SP1

Tags: 2011, content-porter-2009

With a Content Porter export from 2011 SP1 HR1 I see the following error when trying to import into 2011 SP1:

> **Index file has incorrect content.**

I guess it's not possible to port in to a "lower" Tridion even if it differs only by a HR?

Cheers

Comment: As Ryan suggests... the first thing to check with Content Porter is to ensure the exact same CP version - also double check the SPs on the {SQL?} database you're exporting from/importing to; Do you have logging to verbose? does this give any more detail on what index or at what point the fail occurs?

Comment: Cheers Mark, was just really checking if it is possible to port between 2011 SP1 HR1 and 2011 SP1, all things considered. If it is, I'll definitely check the version stuff.

Comment: No worries Neil... I guess if someone tests this it could be useful to validate if some/all item types port also.

Comment: I have content ported forwards a couple of times, 2011 to 2013, but never backwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen this error when you are trying to import using one version of Content Porter but the Content Porter version on the server is different. Making sure these are matched up solved the problem.

Comment: Only just got around to checking this but you're post on Ryan.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you don't want all of the content in the 2011 SP1 instance, or you want to merge it with content already in the 2011 SP1 HR1 instance.

Perhaps DEV is 2011 SP1 HR1 and PROD is 2011 SP1.

If possible, depending on environments, you could backup the 2011 SP1 database and upgrade it to 2011 SP1 HR1. Then the import should be no problem.